# Handler Loading Images From DB - Empty Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, httphandler

I load Images from Database. For the loading purpose i have a generic handler (.ashx) file. 
In the caller page the image url is simply points towards the handler as below.

```
Image myImage = new Image();
myImage.ImageUrl = "/../MyHandler.ashx?imageid=" + myImageId;
```

In the handler image is processed as

```
System.Drawing.Image requestedImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MemoryStream);
requestedImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

When there is no image in the database, for the requested image id, An empty image (Cross) is displayed in the calling aspx page.

once possible option is to set visible = false for the image,

but due to the calling nature in the aspx page i am unable to do this

How can I hide the image in such a scenario?

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no image in the database?
Should it default to a "nopic.jpg" or hide the image or what?

Comment: @SimonMartin I need to hide the image. Edited the last part of the question

Comment: So if the image in the stream is a new Image you don't want to display it. Can you check the properties (e.g. file size) of `requestedImage` and set only make it visible if it's valid. Or create a small 1x1px transparent image?

Comment: @SimonMartin created a 1x1px image. Works fine.Thanks !